# How to connect to MQTT broker with SSL using Java client?

Tags: java, ssl, mqtt

I am trying to connect to Eclipse MQTT broker from https://mosquitto.org/ by using the sample code at

https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.sample.mqttv3app/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/sample/mqttv3app/Sample.java

I generated the certificates with the instructions from this link.

http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/

[image]

I tried many combination but it does not work. How can I get it working?

What should be values here?

```
                case 'k': System.getProperties().put("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", args[++i]); break;
                case 'w': System.getProperties().put("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", args[++i]); break;
                case 'r': System.getProperties().put("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", args[++i]); break;
```

I get this output

```
    "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\jbr\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=64136:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\Github\eclipse-paho\org.eclipse.paho.sample.mqttv3app\bin;D:\Github\eclipse-paho\org.eclipse.paho.sample.mqttv3app\lib\org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.1.jar org.eclipse.paho.sample.mqttv3app.Sample
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.FileLock (file:/D:/Github/eclipse-paho/org.eclipse.paho.sample.mqttv3app/lib/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.1.jar) to method sun.nio.ch.FileLockImpl.release()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.FileLock
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Connecting to ssl://Dactyl:8883 with client ID SampleJavaV3_publish
reason 0
msg MqttException
loc MqttException
cause javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
excep MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:736)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1408)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:722)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 20 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You've not said how it doesn't work, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67016117/edit) the question to include a clear description how it fails including any errors/exception messages. Also which broker are you trying to connect to? And are you trying to do mutual SSL Authentication?

Comment: Also the help output from the linked script clearly states what those values should be.

Comment: @hardillb I have added the output. My question is, will the keys and certificates I have generated work with java client I am using? I am new to SSL so not sure about mutual SSL authentication. And the help output is not clear as I can't figure how to / Which certificate / key paths to pass there.

Comment: You have still not shown what options you are passing to the app to get that error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the help text clearly states

> -r  Use this JKS format keystore to verify the server

You need to [generate Java KeyStores](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfen/index.html) from the files you have.

Since you don't appear to have any client certs/keys we will assume you are just trying to verify the brokers certificate is issued by a trusted CA. So you will need to add the CA cert to a JKS and pass it with the `-r` option.

Comment: I imported ca.crt in a new .jks file using Keystore Explorer and used
 -w pwd -r c:/trash/keys/Dactyl.jks 
as command line parameters. It works now